# Android - Why the animation works on many other list-item when I click one of them in my custom ListView?

Tags: android, listview, animation

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data;  **// contains one Button and two TextViews**

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final titlesHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_title, null);
            holder = new titlesHolder();
            holder.Title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
            holder.Text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
            holder.bt = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (titlesHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.Title.setText(data.get(position).get("itemTitle").toString());
        holder.Text.setText(data.get(position).get("itemText").toString());
        holder.bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.Title, "RotationX", 0.0F, 360.0F).setDuration(500).start();
                holder.Title.clearAnimation();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    private class titlesHolder {
        public TextView Title;
        public TextView Text;
        public Button bt;
    }

}`
```

This is the code of MyAdapter. I add an animation binding to the button. 
However, for instance, when I **click a item whose position is 0**, **then the No.10, No.20... items also animate**. It actually confuse me!

Comment: Why do you always return 0 from `getItemId`?

Comment: I follow the textbook. So what should it return?

Comment: I modify the code as shown. But the problem still exist.

Comment: Make sure you don't have more typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely caused by a result of `ListView`'s memory saving tactics, wherein new rows are created and destroyed as the user scrolls, rather than having all rows available immediately. This makes `ListView` very efficient, but means that "odd" rows will often repeat their state when scrolling, which sounds like the behaviour you're experiencing here.

The solution I recommend is to add an extra variable that stores the state of the row, and then draws its view in `getView()` based on whether or not the row should be in an animation finished or animation ready state.

For example:

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data;  **// contains one Button and two TextViews**
    ArrayList<Boolean> checkedState;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
        checkedState = new ArrayList<>(data.size());
        Collections.fill(checkedState, Boolean.FALSE);
}
```

At the end of your animation, set `checkedState(position)` to true (or `false` again if the animation is going in the opposite direction).

Then, in `getView()`, draw your row based on its position, and how its position correlates to the `checkedState` array.

Comment: It may works. But how to stop a property animation? I could't stop it by calling clearAnimation().

Answer (score 1):

OK I did it finally. The problem results from the ListView's memory saving tactics. So I add a ObjectAnimation called anim in my custom holder to hold the anim of every convertView, and call anim.cancel() everytime getView() is called to build a new view.

> ```
> private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
> ```

```
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final titlesHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_title, null);
            holder = new titlesHolder();
            holder.Title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
            holder.Text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
            holder.bt = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (titlesHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        if (holder.anim != null)
            holder.anim.cancel();
        holder.Title.setText(data.get(position).get("itemTitle").toString());
        holder.Title.setRotationX(0.0f);
        holder.Text.setText(data.get(position).get("itemText").toString());
        holder.bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //data.remove(position);
                //v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                final ObjectAnimator anim;
                anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.Title, "RotationX", 0.0F, 360.0F).setDuration(500);
                holder.anim = anim;
                anim.start();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    private class titlesHolder {
        public TextView Title;
        public TextView Text;
        public Button bt;
        public ObjectAnimator anim;
    }

}
```